# j2me how to put image into List?

Tags: image, list, java-me, midp, lcdui

I have a menu as a class which extends List. There's a native method append(String txt, Image image) which adds a new menu item. The thing is that I want to append a 100% width image as one menu item in the very beginning but if I do this:

```
append("", image);
```

it sets the image size as small as the other's. How can I set its width 100% or at least the size of the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are no documented controls over how list items are drawn. Drawing of the list items is very dependent on the implementation.

Comment: at least, is it possible to set size of the icon and size of the text?

Comment: @Sergey You can set the size of the text by using the `List.setFont(int elementNum, Font font)` method. The `font` argument influences the size of the text. Size of the icon can't be set, unfortunately. You may only try different source image sizes, but behavior on various implementations may be different.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with the use of `J2ME-Polish` Style. You need to set the width of the `MenuItem` and you can achieve it.